# Finding notes in a WAV file

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am looking to figure out how to separate the data in a WAV file into it's constituent notes.
I load the WAV files with:

```
import scipy.io.wavfile as wavfile
rate, data = wavfile.read('scale.wav')
time = np.arange(len(data[:,0]))*1.0/rate
```

and plot with

```
plt.plot(time, data[:,0])
plt.show()
```

this gives me [this picture](https://github.com/wesleybowman/misc/blob/master/Stephanie/WAV.png), which is the piano scale having eight notes in it. I want a way to isolate each note, so that I can then find it's frequency and figure out which note is being played. Once I have the notes isolated, I can take care of the rest.

I have tried finding the maximums, but there are so many and takes multiple iterations to get it down to the maximums I was wanting, and it is an unreliable method since doing too many iterations gets rid of some of the lower amplitude peaks. Getting the length of the note in time as well would be nice.

EDIT: So this is quite complicated like you gentlemen stated. I am now thinking that I just want to find the "extreme" peaks and then find the extreme minimums that go after these peaks, and use that as my note, since we don't need too large a slice of the data to figure out it's frequency. The problem I have with that is, there are a lot of peaks, and it's hard to find only the ones I want. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put an update on this, here is the code we ended up going with. It uses a spectrogram averaged over the columns to figure out where the notes where, and from there using harmonics to figure out the main freqency of that note. Then using abjab to plot the notes on a sheet of music. Isn't perfect, but worked well for a major scale on the clarinet.

We used audacity to cut the noise out of the input audio, and sometimes to amplify the sound.

[Here is the code. Thanks for all your help.](https://github.com/wesleybowman/misc/blob/master/Stephanie/specgram.py)

Comment: hi Wesley, I know it's an old thread, but the code doesn't seem to run, and breaks somewhere inside matplotlib when running plt.specgram(...). Do you , by any chance, have a pip freeze output so I can try your dependency versions?

Comment: Hey @SagiMann, sorry but I do not. This was almost 5 years ago now, so it doesn't surprise me the code is broken.

Comment: I got this code to work, made some quick fixes, leaving this comment for somebody in the future

Comment: code here: https://github.com/wesleybowman/misc/issues/1

Answer (score 4):

Probably the easiest and most interesting thing to do is to calculate a [spectrogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram) of your data, which is basically a plot of the spectra of short sections of your data, plotted against time. Do make the frequency scale logarithmic, since the frequencies of the keys on the piano are spaces exponentially. In Python, you could use the function [specgram](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.specgram) to calculate this, which is included with matplotlib. See for example [this google image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=spectrogram%20music&tbm=isch) for how this looks for different types of music. Also have a look at some computer programs that can play MP3/WAV and have visualization plugins, I remember that Winamp had a way of playing live spectrograms more than 10 years ago.

This is a fun exercise, but let me warn you if you want to use this technique to automatically transcribe the notes of some piece of music: this is a very hard problem, which has been studied by scientists for many years. One problem is for example that most instruments produce a lot of harmonics, which can confuse any algorithm to automatically find notes. And forget about any music with some human voices or percussion, since these produce a lot of wide-band noise (especially the letter 's' and hi-hats), making it almost impossible to recognize any other note.

If you want to get fancy, have a look at the Q-transform (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_Q_transform) and the papers referenced from there). You can consider this as a spectrogram, but with the bins along the frequency axis spaced logarithmically (e.g. bins for every half or quarter note on a piano scale). The advantage of this method over a standard spectrogram is that it has a constant number of frequency bins per note, while a linear frequency scale has few bins for the low notes, and too many for the high notes. I don't know if this is available for numpy, you might have to write the code yourself.

Comment: As a physicist, I understand the complications, but it's for a student I ta who is working on it. It didn't have to be perfect, just really if we get the gist everything should work out for her grade. Using abjad to transcribe. I'm on my phone now, but I'll look into that. Thanks!

Comment: Physicist and piano player here too. And yes, I tried to do this myself too, and basically gave up after seeing how difficult it was. But I won't stop you from trying ...

Answer (score 3):

You've mentioned that you have a background in physics (*which is helpful to know in the original question!*) and you've indicated that you understand how to get the frequency and hence the note from a single piano tone using a [FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform). What's missing then is moving from a function that is localized in both space and time, to one that varies in time. One kind of generalization is [wavelet analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet), where the kernel is

[image]

The choice of g(t-u) gives different results depending on how you want to handle a signal that varies in time. Instead of giving you a spectral frequency, you get a two-dimensional map of spectral frequency *and* time. From this you'll be in a much better shape to extract notes from time-varying signals.

You could, of course, simply have a window where you analyze each block over the window with FFT and extract the largest frequency - but this is brittle, requires hand-tuning and won't work for more complex signals.